# Yahoo! Weather XML Feed allowed to be used in iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, weather-api, yahoo-weather-api

Hey everyone, I'm quite confused when it comes to the legal side of using something like the Yahoo! Weather feed inside my iPhone App.

To be clear, I don't want to actually show any of the info the feed has, but just use that info to trigger events behind the scenes.

I have been researching weather APIs and feeds. Some specifically say they are not to be used in an iOS app. Some say they cannot be resold.

What Weather APIs have you used in your iOS apps? 
What's the community consensus on APIs like this?
Anything with advice to lead me in the right direction.

Much appreciated,

Wesley Dyson

Comment: Really? No one has done/tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently using the service from worldweatheronline.com . They're pretty flexible and provide decent service, more than adequate for my app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think most people here are lawyers, (Neither am I) but from a technical perspective there are three things to note.

1. Nobody (see 2) will know where your information is coming from.
2. The site from whom you are pulling data from can find out.
3. Why not contact Yahoo and see if they will let you use their API. If you are not competing with their/Apple's weather app, it may not be a problem.